# Package or zip archive creation with serverless but without lambda

Tags: zip, serverless-framework

It is needed to create zip file before deployment and there is no lambda functions. Just some folder to zip and upload. Without `functions:` section serverless skip packaging. Any ideas? Any work arounds?

Answer (score 1):

The Serverless Framework generates two things, a zip file containing the code of your Lambda function(s) which is zipped and uploaded to AWS, and the CloudFormation JSON template which is sent to the CloudFormation API.

If you don't have any functions, there are no artifacts/code to zip - so packaging is not necessary.

As your stack only contains CloudFormation - you can simply run `serverless deploy` to apply those changes.